# Кешируется ли curl?

Tags: php, curl

Есть такая проблемка. Curl'ом загружаю данные с внешнего сайта, он перегружен либо на нем проблема какая-то с сервером. То есть бывает при запросе всё хорошо, но и часто - выдает вместо контента `Could not load file or assembly 'ASRKBarcodesStatistic' or one of its dependencies. There is not enough space on the disk. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070070)`. Раз через раз короче.

Пытаюсь решить проблему таким образом. Если получил ошибку - пытаюсь запросить внешние данные еще 3 раза с интервалом, допустим, 5-10 секунд.

Схематично:

```
1-й запрос..
если (ошибка) {
    цикл (i=0; i<3) {
         слип
         повторный запрос..
         если (хорошо) {
             break
         }
    }
}
выдать юзеру хорошо/плохо
```

Но почему то если получил ошибку в 1-ом запросе, то и все остальные повторные 3 раза обязательно будут с ошибкой, сколько не пытался, и увеличивал интервал и количество повторных запросов, словно ответ сервера закешировался и отдает одно и то же.

Почему так?

CURLOPT_VERBOSE

```
* upload completely sent off: 16 out of 16 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
< X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2016 16:04:28 GMT
< Content-Length: 10564
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: Без текста ошибки это ни о чем. А так логика говорит, что если сайт тупит и первый раз выдало например таймаут, то скорее всего и следующие разы упадет с таймаутом

Comment: @Jean-Claude, а из чего следует что между запросами обязательно должны прибежать админы и починить сайт?

Comment: Если вы видите это в контенте, то ребят на сайте место кончилось. и проблемы конфигурации и похоже сам сайт на .NET написан. curl тут не причем

Comment: @PinkTux если вы прочитали, то написано, что сайт работает, но раз через раз выдает контент. Я и пытаюсь спарсить несколько раз, чтобы попасть в те промежутки когда выдается контент, а не бяка.

Comment: В  надежде на то, что сайт самопочинится за несколько секунд? curl тут не причем вообще. Все дело в кривом сайте. Вам чинить нечего. Можете увеличить паузу, но повторюсь - curl тут не причем, он честно отдает то, что ему отдает сайт.

Comment: @Jean-Claude "*но раз через раз выдает контент*" это не называется "работает". Судя по ошибке и серверному ответу - ситуация банально нестабильная на стороне сервера, и здесь нет ничего, что можно было бы подкрутить на стороне запроса.

Comment: @vitidev именно, да, через секунду после бяки уже можно получить требуемый контент. Можно поклацать мышкой быстро 10 раз - половина будет работать, половина нет))

Comment: @vitidev порешал, тупо забыл curl_init() в цикле, в цикле же его закрываю curl_close().

Comment: @PinkTux порешал, тупо забыл curl_init() в цикле, в цикле же его закрываю curl_close().

Answer (score 1):

В общем проблема решена.

При открытии одного curl и работе с ним в цикле ответ сервера один и тот же (wtf?). Если же в цикле каждый раз открывать и закрывать curl - то в одной из попыток контент парсится.

Comment: Возможно, защита есть от парсинга. Ограничение на количество запросов в секунду.

Comment: @ilyaplot не, я пробовал разные варианты по времени.